# Kotlin fragment type mismatch

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am making Master/Detail flow activity in Kotlin. I have mismatch problem with fragments becuase in one activity I need android.support.v4.app.Fragment and in other android.app.Fragment. I implemented my own detail fragment and inherited from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to fix mismatch in supportFragmnet transaction from ListActivity

```
if (mTwoPane) {
    val fragment = GraphDetailFragment().apply {
    arguments = Bundle().apply {
        putString(GraphDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id)
    }
}
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.graph_detail_container, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

But then I have mismatch in fragmentManager from DetailActivity

```
val fragment = GraphDetailFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(GraphDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                        intent.getStringExtra(GraphDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID))
            }
        }

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.graph_detail_container, fragment)
        .commit()
```

and console throws :

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied: public abstract fun add(p0: Fragment!, p1: String!):
>   FragmentTransaction! defined in android.app.FragmentTransaction public
>   abstract fun add(p0: Int, p1: Fragment!): FragmentTransaction! defined
>   in android.app.FragmentTransaction

Is there any simple way how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `DetailActivity` extend `AppCompatActivity`, and then use `supportFragmentManager` in it.

You'll also need to fix your AppTheme in styles.xml. Make sure that the `parent` attribute points to `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.